# Get all bookmark IDs from Word Document

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I want to scan an entire document containing text with the styles Heading 1, Heading 2, normal text and several bullet points / other text (which is basically a tech report). After scanning I want to extract bookmarks assigned to "Heading 2" elements, which also act as sub heading titles within the report.

`getBookmarks()` is defined in the Preview / Beta API which works if my cursor is placed on the "Heading 2" element, as seen below:

```
async function getBookmarks() {
  Word.run(function(context) {        
    var range = context.document.getSelection();
    var bkmrk = range.getBookmarks(true, true);

    return context.sync().then(function() {
      console.log("The bookmarks read from the document was: " + bkmrk.value);
    });
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
      console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
    }
  });
}
```

I've managed to scan the entire document and obtain the "style" attribute as well, as seen from the example code on API documentation:

```
async function getParagraphAll() {   await Word.run(async (context) => {
    // Gets the complete sentence (as range) associated with the insertion point.
    let paragraphs = context.document.body.paragraphs
    paragraphs.load("text, style");

    await context.sync();

    // Expands the range to the end of the paragraph to get all the complete sentences.
    let completeParagraph = paragraphs.items[0]
      .getRange()
      .expandTo(
        context.document
          .getSelection()
          .paragraphs.getFirst()
          .getRange("End")
      )

    paragraphs.load("text, style, hyperlink");
    await context.sync();

    for (let i = 0; i < paragraphs.items.length; i++) {
      console.log(paragraphs.items[i].style);
      //let range = paragraphs.items[i].getRange()   - Why is this not working ?
      //let bkmrk = range.getBookmarks(true, false)  - This doesnt get me the bookmark while its in 
      //the loop scanning the entire document. Is it because it fails on "Normal" style? 
      // Should I filter out "Normal" and only run "getBookmarks" on "Heading" style ?
      console.log(paragraphs.items[i].style);
    }   }); }
```

I've made the reference to Libraries available in the preview API link: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js

I'm struggling to understand why I can get the bookmark at cursor level but when I want to get it for the entire document, it just displays

> do context.sync() before loading any property. There is no need for
>   load.

Comment: You're assigning the current selection to the variable `range` (`var range = context.document.getSelection();`) then querying for a bookmark in that Range. Logically, this will return only the bookmark (if any) of the current selection. If you compare this to the second block of code you should see the difference. Instead, use something more like `var range = context.document.body;`

Comment: The code var range from block 1 is working fine for me. The second block of code (especially the bottom for loop) where I'm getting all the paragraphs in the array and then trying to obtain the bookmark value for "heading" style is what is not working. Should I change the "let range" to context.document.body ? This will not work as its inside the array. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the content of the question. What happens if you work with that first code block, making the suggested substitution? Does `bkmrk` return a collection of bookmarks, then? (I don't have the preview available for testing, which is why I can only suggest what I'd try.)

Comment: So from the first block - console.log("The bookmarks read from the document was: " + bkmrk.value);" returns the right bookmark ID value if the cursor is on the "Heading" tag. The second block's for loop, as you must have noticed, is obtaining each paragraph from a list of paragraphs. I was trying to then query the paragraph items for the bookmark ID to show up (The code that is commented in for loop block). If I uncomment it, I get - "The value of the result object has not been loaded yet. Before reading the value property, call "context.sync()" on the associated request context" error

Comment: And have you tried doing that?

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. So from the first block, if I change to "var range = context.document.body;" as suggested, I get all the bookmarks in an array - ["REF1001", "REF1004", "REF1002", "REF1003"]. Instead of just one, where my cursor is. Brilliant. This is like the VBA's "For i = 1 To objDoc.Bookmarks.Count" which I'm moving away from to port everything in Office JS.